# How to find p for which the profit will be a maximum in this context?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, word-problem

> A producer of computer graphics software finds that selling price p of its software is related to the number of x copies of its software sold annually by the demand equation, x = 10000 -200p  , while its total cost in producing and marketing these x copies is given by the function $$C(x)=50000+5x  $$ Find the price p for which profits will be a maximum. Find the maximum profit earned by selling at this price.

My solution is:
    p(x) = xp(x)-C(x)
         = x(10000-200p)-(50000-5x)
         = -200px+9995x-50000

p'(x) = -200p + 9995

let p'(x) = 0

```
-200p + 9995 = 0
p = -9995/(-200) = 49.975
```

The answer is supposed to be p = $27.50 and P(x) = $51,250

Please help me I'm stuck at this question

Comment: What is &=?  It looks like you have p(x) for both profit and price.  I can't understand your solution.  Please type it up more clearly

Comment: It's a syntax error

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You computed $x^2-C(x)$ instead of $xp(x)-C(x)$

Comment: I didn't do it that way. I did  it  using xp(x) - C(x)

Comment: And the solution for p is 27.50 and P(x) is 51250. That is the answer given in the question. I just have problem getting the solution as mine is way too high

Comment: It looks like you substituted $10000-200p$, which is $x$, for $p(x)$; cf. my answer

Comment: I got the answer thanks for the hint

Comment: I really appreciate it I didn't let p be the function of x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=$ number of copies, $p=$ price, and $P=$ profit.

Then $x=10000-200p$, so $p(x)=\dfrac{10000-x}{200}=50-\dfrac x{200}$.

$P(x)=x p(x) - C(x)=x\left(50-\dfrac x{200}\right)-(50000+5x)=-\dfrac1{200}x^2+45x-50000.$

$P'(x)=-\dfrac1{100}x+45.$

Can you take it from here?

[Solve for $x$ such that $P'(x)=0$; then evaluate $p(x)$ and $P(x)$.]

Comment: Thanks for the hint